# Build fails on adding pod 'Firebase/AppCheck' to the Podfile

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-app-check

I'm using [`firebase_app_check`](https://www.pub.dev/packages/firebase_app_check) package. All good. The following command works as expected.

```
flutter build ios
```

But as soon as I add the following in the `Podfile(ios)`

```
pod 'Firebase/AppCheck'
```

iOS build fails with this error:

> Definition of 'GULAppEnvironmentUtil' must be imported from module 'GoogleUtilities.GULAppEnvironmentUtil' before it is required

What am I missing?

Comment: try deleting Podfile and Podfile.lock in ios folder. Run build again. It will install a new Podfile

Comment: Already tried that, it didn't work. Sorry

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22071 
check this out. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following command it may help you

> run flutter clean

> run flutter pub get

> go to your project iOS directory and run pod install then run pod update

if this issue is because of outdated pod files

Comment: ca you share your Xcode version

Comment: I already tried them before starting a bounty, sorry didn't help. `Xcode: Version 13.1`